# Expression for an image of a vector - is it invertible

Tags: matrices

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&&2&&-3&&4\\
5&&0&&2&&-2\\
2&&1&&1&&2\\
0&&0&&3&&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I wanted to confirm that if I use $(w, x,$$ y, z)$ would the image of the vector be:

```
-w + 2x - 3y + 4z
5w + 2y - 2z
2w + x + y + 2z
3y - 2z
```

Could anybody provide some help?

If i wanted to check if this matrix is invertible how would i go about doing that?

Comment: How did you mix $\;w,x,y,z\;$ there in the first line?

Comment: @Timbuc - i multiplied the w,x,y,z with the vector to get the image

Comment: Ok, so then where do the $\;r,s,t,u\;$ come from??

Comment: oh i copied it in wrong - lemme change it

Comment: @Timbuc - changed it

Comment: Then yes: it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is correct, however, it may be able to be simplified.

One thing you could do is determine the reduced row echelon form (rref) of your matrix.  Then the image (or column space) of your matrix is the column space of the rref of your matrix.

Comment: Thank you i will have a go

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can tell you whether or not a matrix is invertible (see [The Invertible Matrix Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem).)

One of these is whether the matrix has full rank. The reduced row echelon form can tell you the rank of a matrix. If the RREF has no rows/columns that are all $0$, then the matrix has full rank. This is equivalent to saying that the dimension of the rowspace (or columnspace) is $n$ (in this case, $n=4$).